# Ruby on Rails, trim the text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, web

Why this code is not work?

```
<%= truncate(post.text, :length => post.text.rindex(".", 500)) %>
```

I need to trim the text on last dot before 500th symbol.

Comment: @Mischa Then it would stop on the *first* period.

Comment: `<%= post.text[0..post.text.rindex('.', 500)]%>.` this is what you want?

Comment: @meagar, never mind, didn't read carefully

Comment: Can you give an example? because it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  the `:separator` option. It will truncate at the dot before 500 characters

`truncate(post.text, :length => 500, :separator => '.')`